# Set orientation of pivot point

Tags: origin

I'm just starting with Blender (2.93) and have some CAD experience (recently FreeCAD).  I've seen a number of posts and discussions, but I'm beginning to think that there is no straightforward solution for my problem.

I'm trying to set the orientation of a pivot point accurately.  As an example, presume a cube that has been moved/rotated arbitrarily with its own pivot point also moved and reoriented.  I can easily move the pivot point to a vertex of the cube, but I cannot manage to align the axes along the edges of the cube.

I've also tried creating a custom transform, but I have the same problem in that I can't reliably set the orientation of the axes (if I choose Face, I get the Z axis along the normal, but can't control X or Y).

It seems this should be simple and, coming from the CAD world, pretty basic.  What am I missing?  On a bit more philosophical level, does this just turn out not to be an issue in Blender (even for hard surface modeling)?

Pointers to a useful tutorial or the like would really be appreciated.

Thanks,
--Don

Comment: Not sure I understand exactly what you want to obtain, but what about using an empty with a copy rotation constraint set to the cube. Then use this empty to create a custom transform orientation?

Comment: you can manipulate the origin orientation, so you can align the origin with the custom orientation, the problem of a simple edge is that you can set only one direction, but maybe show some screenshots of your situation?

Answer (score 2):

There are  quite a few more 'official' ways to do this, e.g. using an aligned Empty, or <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Numpad 7</kbd> aligning the orthogonal view to a reference face, and then aligning your pivot to the 'View' orientation, or vertex-snapping a helper-cube...

... but here's a hack for speed. If you create a transform orientation from an edge or 2 points on your desired pivot Y, and align the pivot to it, then <kbd>R</kbd><kbd>Y</kbd> rotation-snapping the pivot with 'Active' to 'Vertex' around  Y, strangely works. It seems always to be at a multiple of 45 degrees from the target. You can spot that angle, and manually (numerically) rotate the remainder:

[image]